# Post list of string null on web api controller

Tags: json, string, list, post, asp.net-web-api

In my web api project, I got a controller named ContactController and a method named Synchro in it which waits for a list of string as below:

```
[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/Contact/Synchro")]
    public IHttpActionResult Synchro([FromBody]List<string> listNumTel)
    {
        List<Profil> listContact = new List<Profil>();
        if (listNumTel.Count() > 0)
        {
            try
            {
                listContact = Librairie.Contacts.getContactSync(listNumTel);
                return Ok(listContact);
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                return InternalServerError(e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

To test that method, I've created the ajax called below:

```
$("#btn_synchro").click(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/Contact/Synchro',
        type: 'POST',
        data: {
            "listNumTel": [
                "+33640512999",
                "+33640522997",
                "+33640182998",
                "+33640742996"]
        },
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Synchro réussi: ' + data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Erreur lors de la synchro");
        }
    })
});
```

When I test on debug mode, the call works fine but the method get a null list. I checked if the json is valid and it is. Does Somebody sees what could be wrong ? Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you check your request from the browser if it sends it as content type "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ?

Comment: The content-type of the request appears to be: application/json

Comment: Well, try to set it at "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" because I think your backend won't understand it's an incoming POST request. jQuery seems to be supposed to set it to this by default, but try to explicitly setting it in `contentType`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the answers, but I've just found out the solution. It was all about JSON sent. To send a list of string by an ajax call for example, the JSON should looks like below the variable listNumero

```
("#btn_synchro").click(function () {
    var listNumero = 
        [   '+33640532999',
            '+33640532997',
            '+33640532998',
            '+33640532996'];

    $.ajax({
        url: '../api/Contact/Synchro',
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(listNumero),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Synchro réussi: ' + data);
        },
        error: function (request, error) {
            alert("Erreur lors de la synchro");
        }
    })
});
```

You can compare to my post, the JSON is different. Now my web api controller can get the values from the list.